# Bash - difference between <<EOF and <<'EOF'

Tags: bash, heredoc

[GNU Bash - 3.6.6 Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)

> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> If any part of word is **quoted**, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.

If I single-quote EOF, it works. I think because bash **/bin/bash** process to be invoked gets un-expanded strings and then the invoked process interprets the lines.

```
$ /bin/bash<<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
echo $BASH_VERSION
EOF               
3.2.57(1)-release
```

However, the below is causing an error. I thought BASH_VERSION would have been expanded and the version of current bash process is passed to the **/bin/bash** process to be invoked. But not working.

```
$ /bin/bash<<EOF 
#!/bin/bash
echo $BASH_VERSION
EOF               
/bin/bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: line 2: `echo 5.0.17(1)-release'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> /bin/bash<<EOF 
> #!/bin/bash
> echo $BASH_VERSION
> EOF
> ```

As you can infer from the error message, the heredoc is being expanded to:

```
/bin/bash<<EOF 
#!/bin/bash
echo 5.0.17(1)-release
EOF
```

It sounds like that's what you expect: it's being expanded to the outer shell's version. The problem isn't with the heredoc or the expansion; it's that unquoted parentheses are a syntax error. Try running just the `echo` command by hand and you'll get the same error:

```
$ echo 5.0.17(1)-release
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

To fix this, you could add extra quotes:

```
/bin/bash<<EOF 
echo '$BASH_VERSION'
EOF
```

This will work and print the outer shell's version. I used single quotes to demonstrate that these quotes will *not* inhibit variable expansion. The outer shell doesn't see these quotes. Only the inner shell does.

(I also got rid of the `#!/bin/bash` shebang line. There's no need for it since you're explicitly invoking bash.)

**However, quoting is not 100% robust.** If `$BASH_VERSION` happened to contain single quotes you'd have a problem. The quotes make parentheses `(` `)` safe but they aren't foolproof. As a general technique, if you want this to be completely safe *no matter what special characters are in play* you'll have to jump through some ugly hoops.

1. Use `printf '%q'` to escape all special characters.

   ```
   /bin/bash <<EOF
   echo $(printf '%q' "$BASH_VERSION")
   EOF
   ```

   This will expand to `echo 5.0.17\(1\)-release`.
2. Pass it in as an environment variable and use `<<'EOF'` to disable interpolation inside the script.

   ```
   OUTER_VERSION="$BASH_VERSION" /bin/bash <<'EOF'
   echo "$OUTER_VERSION"
   EOF
   ```

   This would be my choice. I prefer use the `<<'EOF'` form whenever possible. Having the parent shell interpolate the script being passed to a child shell can be confusing and difficult to reason about. Also, the explicit `$OUTER_VERSION` variable makes it crystal clear what's happening.
3. Use `bash -c 'script'` instead of a heredoc and then pass the version in as a command-line argument.

   ```
   bash -c 'echo "$1"' bash "$BASH_VERSION"
   ```

   I might go with this for a single-line script.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't quote `EOF`, variables in the heredoc are expanded by the original shell before passing it as input to the invoked shell.  So it's equivalent to executing

```
echo 3.2.57(1)-release
```

in the invoked shell. That's not valid `bash` syntax, so you get an error.

Quoting the word prevents variable expansion, so the invoked shell receives `$BASH_VERSION` literally, and expands it itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the quotes prevent any changes in the here document, so the sub-shell sees `echo $BASH_VERSION` and it expands the string and echoes it.

In the second case, the absence of quotes means that the first shell expands the information and it sees `echo 3.2.57(1)-release`, and if you type that at the command line, you get the syntax error.

If you used `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` in both, then both would work, but different shells would expand `$BASH_VERSION`.